# Как на андроид обработать нажатие на кнопку Home?

Tags: actionbar, android, java

Скажите пожалуйста как на Андроид при нажатии на кнопку Home actionbar , вывести например

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int
> featureId, MenuItem item) {
>
> ```
> switch (item.getItemId()) {
> case android.R.id.home:
> ```
>
> > ```
> >     System.out.println("Hello World!");
> > ```
>
> ```
>     break;
>
> }
>
> return true; }
> ```